# Jquery dialog('open') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page, which is inserted into another page  where the inserted page contains a button that will open a dialog when clicked. Unfortunately, when clicked the dialog will not open. Chrome developer tools do not show any errors and using console.log show that the element is being found.

Code snippet is as follows:

```
<input type ="button" value ="click me" onclick ='$('.opendialog').dialog ('open')'/>

<div id ='opendialog'><div>
```

I have tried variations that used the document ready function syntax and that didn't work either.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't you need onclick="..." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the  tag, set the dialog initialisation, to be after the html tags - and it that's all

Answer (score 1):

`opendialog` is an `id`, as you can see here

```
<div id ='opendialog'><div>
```

while you use the class selector of `.opendialog` to select it instead of the id selector of `#opendialog`. Also, make sure you either escape the string enclosing character or use quotes.

Long story short:

```
<input type ="button" value ="click me" onclick ='$("#opendialog").dialog ("open")'/>
```

Comment: Yes I have even tried the # syntax and that didn't work either

Comment: @Andy5, do you still have apostrophes inside the onclick value, or have you changed them to quotes as I have shown you?

Comment: Yes, I was typing this whilst travelling on a train

Comment: Can you create a fiddle about your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no because it is on an air gapped network

Comment: No errors in the console and I have used console.log around the jQuery function and it shows that it has found the element

Comment: @Andy5, what do you get if you run console.log($('.opendialog').dialog + "") ?

Comment: When I do that I get in console the call to dialog which appears to me as though it is working but as I say nothing is being rendered

Comment: @Andy5, can you show me what is the function that is displayed there?

Comment: Not to worry.  I fixed it by moving the script tag after the html tags

Comment: @Andy5, it is not clear what was your problem. Can you edit your question and add the structure you used and what was needed to be changed?